# How to change items under edit tab on user account page?

Tags: 7, theming, users

I know how to remove the user tab completely from the user menu with hooks.

I want to know where I can find the template file that render the items under this tab (or where I can edit what to show under this tab) as I want to hide some parts for all users).

I have tried ***Home » Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings***.
But it only changes items on the user account page **NOT** the edit tab.

Comment: install devel module then you get any field of users

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to hide fields or properties from the user account edit form, you can create a custom module implementing either [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7). The ID of the form in question is 'user_profile_form'.

Answer (score 3):

I come from check how the page is created and for this Drupal use various function. So I think that the best for you is install the [Theme developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module with the [simplehtmldom API](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplehtmldom) module (**You must use simplehtml API version 7.x-1.12 if you want Theme Developer to function properly.**)

> Theme Developer relies on the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module as a dependency. Once
>   enabled, you may click on any part of the page and a sexy popup
>   display shows which theme function/template outputted the HTML, and
>   what other files could have done so. Armed with this info, a themer
>   may quickly and accurately override the presentation. Further, all the
>   variables passed into the template/function are presented for review.

To learn how to use the module you can read (or watch) about the [Theme developer module](https://www.drupal.org/node/209561).

Answer (score 2):

If the only challenge is to hide some account required fields on the register tab, you can also use [field_permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) together with [required_by_role](https://www.drupal.org/project/required_by_role).